# Drop down box in Node.js not providing JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, sqlite

I am trying to have a drop down box display information contained within a SQLite3 Database. There are three entry names:Philip, John & Carol with respective fields and data for each name which is each person's profession an jpg image.

I am attempting to do this with node.js and jquery. Please see the code below. I keep getting an error such as below:

GET http://localhost:5000/nameJohn 404 (Not Found)

I am guessing, it may have to do with the ajax get call request below with the name id from the database:
          $('#pet_owners').on('change',function(){
          $.get('name'+this.value,function(data){

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    <HTML>
    Name:
    <select id="pet_owners">
      <option value="Philip">Philip</option>
      <option value="John">John</option>
      <option value="Carol">Carol</option>
      </select> 
      <select id="info">
      </select>
    </HTML> 
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    <SCRIPT>

    <JQUERY>

    $('#pet_owners').on('change',function(){
    $.get('name'+this.value,function(data){

     for(var j = 0; j < length; j++)
     {

       $('#info').contents().remove();
       var newOption = $('<option/>');
       newOption.attr('text', data[j].text);
       newOption.attr('value', data[j].value);
       $('#info').append(newOption);
         }
      });
    });

    </SCRIPT>
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    <JAVASCRIPT MAIN FILE>


    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.static('static_files'));
    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
    const db = new sqlite3.Database('pets.db');

    app.get('/users/:userid', (req, res) => {
    const nameToLookup = req.params.userid; // matches ':userid' above
    db.all(
      //sql query:
      'SELECT * FROM users_to_pets WHERE name=$name',
      //parameters to pass into SQL query:
      {
        $name: nameToLookup
      },

      res.json(nameToLookup));
     });

     app.listen(5000, () => {
     console.log('Server started at http://localhost:5000/');
     });

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    <SQLITE3 DATABASE CREATION SCRIPT>

    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
    const db = new sqlite3.Database('pets.db');

    // run each database statement *serially* one after another
    // (if you don't do this, then all statements will run in parallel,
    //  which we don't want)
    db.serialize(() => {
    // create a new database table:
    //db.run("CREATE TABLE users_to_pets (name VARCHAR(255), job 
     VARCHAR(255), pet VARCHAR(255))");
     db.run("CREATE TABLE users_to_pets (name TEXT, job TEXT, pet TEXT)");


   // insert 3 rows of data:

   db.run("INSERT INTO users_to_pets (name, job, pet) VALUES ('Philip', 
  'professor', 'cat.jpg')");
   db.run("INSERT INTO users_to_pets (name, job, pet) VALUES ('John', 
  'student', 'dog.jpg')");
   db.run("INSERT INTO users_to_pets (name, job, pet) VALUES ('Carol', 
   'engineer', 'bear.jpg')");

   //db.run("INSERT INTO users_to_pets VALUES ('Philip', 'professor', 
   'cat.jpg')");
   //db.run("INSERT INTO users_to_pets VALUES ('John', 'student', 
   'dog.jpg')");
   //db.run("INSERT INTO users_to_pets VALUES ('Carol', 'engineer', 
    'bear.jpg')");

    console.log('successfully created the users_to_pets table in pets.db');

   // print them out to confirm their contents:
    db.each("SELECT name, job, pet FROM users_to_pets", (err, row) => {
      console.log(row.name + ": " + row.job + ' - ' + row.pet);
    });
   });

   db.close();
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

Try `localhost:5000/users/nameJohn` instead of `localhost:5000/nameJohn`. That should fix the 404 error.

Comment: What about `$.get('name'+this.value,function(data){`, and the whole sql section?

Comment: what about it? @LawrenceCherone